# Lodash using curry with bind cause a typescript error

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

I'm trying to use the `bind` method with `curry`, but it gives me a type error.

```
const curried = curry(this.method.bind(this));
const getSomething = curried(a, b);
```

Getting TS error from getSomething:

> expected 0-1 arguments but got 2.

When I am not using the bind method it's not complaining.

```
const curried = curry(this.method);
const getSomething = curried(a, b);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that this is the signature of bind:

```
bind(this: Function, thisArg: any, ...argArray: any[]): any;
```

So the return of `bind` for a function is `any`, `curry` still works because `any` can be converted to any other type, so the first overload in declaration order of `curry` is used namely this one:

```
curry<T1, R>(func: (t1: T1) => R, arity?: number): CurriedFunction1<T1, R>;
```

With `T1` and `R` being inferred to `{}`.

This is a reason to stay away from `bind`, it loses type info. It is difficult to write a general type safe version of `bind`, since it can bind both `this` and function arguments, but a version that just binds `this` and preserves type info in easy to write:

```
function typedThisBind<T1, T2, T3, T4, R>(fn: (t: T1, t2: T2, t3: T3, t4 : T4) => R, thisArg: any) : typeof fn
function typedThisBind<T1, T2, T3, R>(fn: (t: T1, t2: T2, t3: T3) => R, thisArg: any) : typeof fn
function typedThisBind<T1, T2, R>(fn: (t: T1, t2: T2) => R, thisArg: any) : typeof fn
function typedThisBind<T1, R>(fn: (t: T1) => R, thisArg: any) : typeof fn
function typedThisBind<R>(fn: () => R, thisArg: any) : () => R
function typedThisBind(fn: Function, thisArg: any) : any {
    return fn.bind(thisArg);
}
```

Now using this version of bind all should work as expected (for functions with up to 5 arguments, but you can easily add more):

```
class Foo {
    method(a: number, b: number) {}
    m(){
        const curried = curry(typedThisBind(this.method, this));
        const getSomething = curried(0, 0); // Works as expected.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, helpful as always.